# Plotly JS smart scale Y axis range

Tags: plotly

I have the following chart :
[image]

But in such cases when only 1 value is totally different than the others it's not possible to read the values of the rest, for example im not sure where the value is : 10 or 15 etc.

So i'm trying to make the scale for Y kind of custom/dynamic or whatever and to display the chart like this :
[image]

The idea is to have different distance between 0 and 20 and between 20 and 150 for example.
I've tried with such configuration :

```
yaxis: {autorange: true}
```

but this doesn't really make any difference.

My example is here: https://codepen.io/hbirimirski/pen/KKmKxJa

Comment: The easiest approach in such a case is to set up a second axis. `"yaxis2":{"anchor":"x","overlaying":"y","side":"right"}`

Comment: it doesn't make any difference , just moved the y axis legend on right side ?

Comment: I usually code in python, so I made an HTML file of the results of creating the graph in python and shared the part of the graph corresponding to the second axis from the HTML file.

Comment: thanks for your help , but this create more confusing and the point with value 170 is not even visible , it's not working for me

Comment: I'll remove Colab since my suggestion didn't help you, and you can change the y-axis limit to 200 as well.